# How return .zip file to .sketch file?

Tags: zip, sketch-3, sketchapp

In version 43 of Sketch users can get content of the file by change .sketch extension on .zip and after unarchiving this.
But how I can return .zip file to .sketch file?
Now when I change extension I get an error after opening the file "The document “Untitled.sketch” could not be opened."

How solve this?

Comment: **Solution:**
I have been found the solution. For correct file creating user must zipping content of the folder "Untitled", not the folder.

Answer (score 0):

The trick work fine with the last version of sketch (50.2). Just try to update sketch and it will work for you again.

Comment: thanks! But it works and in 43+ too.
On sketch forum, I got the solution. I have been added it above :)